# Dropdown selected value in a SESSION variable accross different pages doesn't persist

Tags: php, html, sql-server, session-variables

On my `list.php` page, the user can choose a country from the drop-down to show the SQL server's data for the selection. On this selection, the user gets the option to update/edit the values on an `edit.php` page. When the user submits the changes on the `edit.php` page, they are redirected to a `save.php` page and then back to the initial `list.php` page. I was wondering if it's possible to use the `SESSION` variable to store the initial country selection so the user gets the same selection when redirected to `list.php`. I've tried to use `session_start ();`, but couldn't get it to work.

**EDITED**

This are pieces of my code:

Top of `list.php`:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Form:

```
<form name="frmname" id="frmid" action="list.php" method="POST" >
<h4>From: <input type="text" size="6" name="start_date" pattern="[0-9/]+" 
placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
To: <input type="text" size="6" name="end_date" pattern="[0-9/]+" 
placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
<select name="RegioSelect" onchange="this.form.submit();" ><option><?php echo $_SESSION['RegioSelect']; ?></option>
```

Dropdown populated by:

```
$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT CountryRegionName FROM tKein23 ORDER BY CountryRegionName";
$stmt1 = $conn->query( $query1 );
while ($data = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value="'.$data['CountryRegionName'].'">';
    echo $data['CountryRegionName']; 
    echo "</option>";
}
```

Then I tried `SESSION_START()`:

```
<h4><input type="submit" value="Show" name="Selection" />
</select>
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST["RegioSelect"])){
        $_SESSION['RegioSelect'] = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
    }
```

Now, on other pages, I do get the `$_SESSION['RegioSelect']` variable. On `list.php`, I get the variable in the drop-down but no submission.

Comment: `session_start()` has to be called **BEFORE** any output to the browser

Comment: I putted the session_start() code on the top of the pages, before html tags but it don's seems to work when I'm redirected to list.php don't get the selected country `<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["RegioSelect"])){
 $_SESSION['RegioSelect'] = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
}
?>`

Comment: The `$_SESSION['RegioSelect'] = $_POST["RegioSelect"];` is on the `list.php` ? otherwise the `if()` will not get executed

Comment: OK did that, what piece of code should I put on the other pages? Only the session_start();?

Comment: Could the form on list.php be submitted on load? How?

Answer (score 1):

session_start() must come first, before any other ouput. Not only before html on your php script, but before any browser output.

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/session_start)

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
    <body>
        ...
        ...
        <h4><input type="submit" value="Show" name="Selection" />
        </select>
        </form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST["RegioSelect"]))
        $_SESSION['RegioSelect'] = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the form is on the same page, make sure to move the

```
if (isset($_POST["RegioSelect"]))
    $_SESSION['RegioSelect'] = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
```

to the top - right **below** the `session_start()` and **before** the `<html>`

otherwise you have to reload the page first - which is probably not what you want

from there on you can also do redirects to other pages via `header()`

Comment: From the save.php already do a header() redirect back to list.php, there's when I need to get the from submitted in order to get the selection back. Tried JavaScript but the onLoadSubmit() function get in a loop, so actually I need this function to be ran just once but I don't get it to work.