# JavaScript onload function loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have a JavaScript function that submits a form on page load, the problem, is that this function never stop, it get in a loop for ever, I'm trying to stop it when condition is met but for some reason it doesn't work.

the condition is when `i==1` but it keeps going for ever.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
function loadit(){
if (i==1){
    return;
    }else{
        document.frm.submit();
        i++
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="loadit()">
```

Comment: `document.frm.submit();` where is form ?

Comment: Below in the <body> tag of the page

Comment: why do you want to submit a form onload ?

Comment: The form has a drop-down, from SQL server, on this page I use a SESSION_START() functions that return a value that is the selection of the drop-down, so when the user get back to the page the form get the value of the SESSION in the form is submitted. Yesterday I posted about the SESSION: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384283/dropdown-selected-value-in-a-session-variable-accross-different-pages/46384775#46384775)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the loop is that you are reseting `i` back to 0 at each load time (thus, your loop), you need to store the `i` somewhere else, that checks if the form has been submitted, and then increases by increments.

So this would be a simple example using PHP. It will look for the `i` value in the URL param, under `i=?`. If it's not set, then automatically set it to 0.

```
<?php
// this will check for the i in the URL, if it's not there, set $i to 0
$i = (isset($_GET['i']) ? urlencode($_GET['i']) : 0)
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function loadit() {
        // set `i` to `$i`
        var i = <?= $i; ?>;
        var frm = $('#form');
        var con = $('#content');

        if (i == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            frm.submit();
            i++;
        }
    });
</script>

</head>

<body onload="loadit()">

<!-- increment $i for the action field. -->
<form id="form" action="?i=<?= ++$i; ?>" method="post">

    <input id="content" type="hidden" value="Something_here">

</form>


</body>
```

Another method is to use Ajax, and use the response to determine whether or not it needs to be submitted again.

Comment: This solved my issue when returning to the original page, on my form i have drop-down with a `onchange` attribute to submit the form, when it submit the form the loop come up once again.
`<form name="frm" id="frm" action="?i=<?= ++$i; ?>" method="POST" >
<h4>From: <input type="text" size="6" name="start_date" pattern="[0-9/]+" placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
To: <input type="text" size="6" name="end_date" pattern="[0-9/]+" placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
<select id="RegioSelectid" name="RegioSelect" onchange="this.form.submit();" ><option><?php echo $_SESSION['RegioSelect'];?></option>`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is it not working? @KelvinMorel

Comment: My `onchange="this.form.submit();"` attribute starts the crazy form submit loop again.

Comment: @KelvinMorel I will look at it

Comment: SOLVED by changing `if (i == 1) { return true;` to `if (i >= 1) { return;`

Answer (score -2):

you submit a form so its refresh your page and then it hits the onload again.
if you want the form to get submitted every time the page load do is with ajax.

you can test it by removeing the `document.frm.submit();` and do console.log.